# How to fix "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer" error in C?

Tags: c

I wrote the following code to solve a problem in codewars:

```
char *series_sum(unsigned long int n){
    double sum=0;
    static char a[10];
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){sum=sum+1.0/(3*i-2);}
    sprintf(a,"%.2lf",sum);
    return a;
}
```

The problem is fairly simple, it just wants you to print the nth partial sum of a series and return it as a string with 2 decimal points ("a.bc").
However i get the error:

> munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000006031b1

EDIT: This is the code that tests the function.

```
#include <criterion/criterion.h>
#include <stddef.h>

char *series_sum(const size_t n);

Test(ExampleTests, ShouldPassAllTheTestsProvided) {
 {
   const char *expected = "1.00";
   char *received = series_sum(1);
   cr_assert_str_eq(expected, received, "Expected: %s Received: %s", expected, received);
   free(received); received = NULL;
 }

 {
   const char *expected = "1.25";
   char *received = series_sum(2);
   cr_assert_str_eq(expected, received, "Expected: %s Received: %s", expected, received);
   free(received); received = NULL;
 }

 {
   const char *expected = "1.39";
   char *received = series_sum(3);
   cr_assert_str_eq(expected, received, "Expected: %s Received: %s", expected, received);
   free(received); received = NULL;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The code you are providing is not the problem. The code that you call it with (e.g. your main-function) might be.

Comment: (not the cause of the crash but note that it does not make sense to declare `int i` if it should run up to `unsigned long n`)

Comment: I somehow missed that, I edited the post and added the missing code.

Comment: Thank you for updating your post.  Bernd Elkemann's "guess" was exactly correct - you're trying to "free" a pointer that you never "malloc'ed".  Please verify that removing the "free" works.  And please "upvote" and "accept" his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no information about your other code yet, let me speculate: the calling code does something like:

```
int main(void) {
    char* Pointer = series_sum(999);
    free(Pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

That free-call tries to free a static. You can call free on pointers that you got from malloc. You should not try to call it on a static buffer.

Comment: You were correct the first time: `"The code you are providing is not the problem. The code that you call it with (e.g. your main-function) might be"`.  Your guess is a good guess ... but we shouldn't be guessing.  The OP needs to *TELL* us.  By reproducing the problem with an [MCVE].  Or by stepping through the code in the debugger, and showing us the line where it actually crashes.  Even though sometimes you get lucky - "Guessing", in the long run, is counter-productive :(